# Why does OpenSSL default the CRL to expire in 30 days?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

[EasyRSA sets the default CRL expiration to 180 days](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=27090), and [this other SE answer](https://serverfault.com/a/901602/596851) says the default is 30 days.

In OpenVPN the CRL is just a static file named "crl.pem" and the file is never passed to the end-user; instead, it stores revoked client certificates.  Since it is all server-side managed and not downloaded by the client, should it be safe to have a very long lifetime?

**What is the purpose of a CRL having such a short lifetime?**

I would think you would want this to be "forever" or at least a long time because when the CRL expires it breaks the application using the CRL (OpenVPN in our case).

Comment: If set to forever how would clients know when to look for newly revoked certificates?

Comment: Although partially related to programs some of which sometimes run on Unix, this isn't really a Unix question and I suggest it would be better suited on security.SX where you might start with https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36682/why-are-certificate-revocation-list-periodically-renewed and maybe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35117/how-does-an-offline-ca-revoke-certificates